# Check if $\sin(x) = O(x)$ for all real numbers

Tags: calculus, computer-science, computational-complexity

> Check if $\sin(x) = O(x)$ for all real numbers

For this proposition to be true we must find such $C > 0$ that 
$$|\sin(x)| \le C|x|$$
But since it is known that $|\sin(x)| \le |x|$ it's enough to pick $C = 1$ and this works. 
Is it the correct solution or I'm missing something? I have just learned about the big-O notation still don't feel comfortable with it.

Comment: @Aemilius : Yes it is correct.

Comment: @NickA I think it is not about calculating sin(x), but you must check that you can find M such that for "big enough" value of x, |sin(x)| <= M*|x|. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition

Comment: @cro ah i see, thanks

Comment: You don't even have to know that |sin(x)| <= |x| for all x. sin(x) is at most 1, so for any x>=1 you can pick M=1, and the inequality holds. In fact, from this follows that sin(x)=O(1).

Comment: The question, as phrased, seems ill-posed. A function is $O(\cdot)$ of another *at a specific point* (typically, at $\infty$ or $0$), asymptotically.  As stated, the question looks nonsensical.

Comment: @croraf How would I know? That'd make more sense to me, but that should be specified *by the OP*, as written in (or in the context of) the question they were asked.

Comment: @ClementC.: Even better would be to say that a function is big-O of another _for a specific limit_ such as $x\to+\infty$ or $x\to 0$, or for that matter for $x\to 0^+$. (For example, $e^{1/x}$ is $o(x)$ for $x\to 0^-$ but not for $x\to 0$).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Fair, the terminology is even clearer like that (although it's possible for $\infty$, it's hard to consider $0^+$ as a "point.")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the standard definition of $O$ used in computer science, a function $f(n)$ to be big $O$ of $g(n)$ as $n \to \pm \infty$, it must be the case that there exists $x_0 \in \Bbb R$ and $M >0$ such that for all $|x| \ge x_0$, $|f(x)| \le M|g(x)|$. That is, $f$ be bounded by a multiple of $g$ *eventually* as $x \to \infty$.

So certainly you could take $C = 1$ and then $|\sin x| \le 1\cdot|x|$ so $\sin(x) = O(x)$. But $\sin x + 1$ is also $O(x)$ even though $|\sin 0 + 1| \not\le C|0|$ for any $C > 0$. It doesn't matter what happens to your function at small values of $x$, just as $x \to \infty$. (So we may, for example take $C =1$ and $x_0 = 1$ and $|\sin x| \le 1 \le 1|x|$ for all $|x| \ge |x_0|$.) Also $\sin x$ is in fact $O(1)$, even ($C = 1$ would work.)

---

As mentioned in the comment's by ClementC and the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), big $O$ notation can also be used as $x \to a$ for any real number $a$. ($a = 0$ is used quite commonly in numerical analysis and physics.) If what you mean when you said $\sin x = O(x)$ "for all all real numbers" was to find if $\sin x = O(x)$ as $x \to a$ for every $a \in \Bbb R$, then your global bound $|\sin x| \le |x|$ does indeed establish this.

Comment: The big-Oh notation is very often used at $0$ (instead of $\infty$), even in computer science. Assuming by default it's for $x\to\infty$ is quite an oversight, especially for a bounded function like $\sin$.